# What's the difference between Red Orchestra 2: Heroes of Stalingrad with Rising Storm Normal Edition and the Deluxe Edition?

Tags: red-orchestra-2

So, I want to buy this game, but I'm still wondering what is the difference between them.
Any idea?
Like, tell me the detailed answer, maybe like gun unlocking a bit easier, exclusive items, etc...

> Buy RO2 with Rising Storm
> WEEK LONG DEAL! Offer ends 6 September
> -75%Rp 135 999
> Rp 33 999
>
> Buy RO2 with Rising Storm - RO 2 Digital Deluxe Edition
> WEEK LONG DEAL! Offer ends 6 September
> -75%Rp 199 999
> Rp 49 999

Note that im from Indonesia. The price difference is only like 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Steam Store Description](http://store.steampowered.com/app/35450/) (you'll need to extend it to see this), the "Digital Deluxe Edition" adds:

- Day 1 Unlock of the Elite Assault Weapons (MKb 42(H) and AVT-40) and Semi Auto Sniper Weapons (SVT-40 and G 41(W))
- Team Fortress 2 German and Russian hats, The Stahlhelm and The Pilotka ("Genuine" if bought during pre-purchase, so not any more)
- Two new characters for Killing Floor - Russian and German Soldier Re-enactors, Nikolai and George

So, 4 unlocked guns and some cosmetics for 2 other games.

Comment: I think its funny how Killing Floor has gone in the same path as TF2 with all the exclusive items and such. Good answer, poor question haha

Comment: @Mumford451 It's not that bad. The write's obviously not used to the english language, so the language is a bit wonky. But it's easy to see what's being asked. And, after seeing the dreadfully organized Steam page, the confusion is also understandable.

Comment: I'm sorry DJ Pirtu I was not insulting the question itself or the English.  All that is fine, I just think you could have looked at the details yourself within the Steam deals to see the differences [even if they were subtle]